# Basic Authentication when redirecting to external url in JSF

Tags: jsf, redirect, servlets

How can I add basic authentication to a request when redirecting to an external url in JSF.

I need to download a report(provided by SSRS in Excel format) on button click from JSF application, the url for the report is in the format -

http://report-server-host/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?reportName&rs:Format=Excel

I found a way to redirect to this page from backing bean using FacesContext.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(path);
```

But the report-server need basic authentication, how can I add it when doing this redirect?

Comment: The external context is a servlet-context. Effectively making this not even a jsf question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the username and password in the URL itself like this

http://username:password@report-server-host/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?reportName&rs:Format=Excel

---

To convert the Basic authentication header to username:password format use Base64 decoder.

If the header is something like `Basic {TOKEN}` where `{TOKEN}` is the Base64 encoded string ( something like `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` ), then the redirect URL should be

```
  String auth = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(TOKEN));

  path = path.replaceFirst("://", "://" + auth + "@");

  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(path);
```

Since I don't have the reputation to comment, I'm replying to your comment here. The `username:password@` part doesn't need to be URL escaped.

Comment: Thanks, but the username has '/' in it and password has a '@'. How do I escape these characters?

Comment: I tried to open the url after adding the encoded username:password, the browser is still asking for a user/password combination again.

Comment: Now my url is -  http://token@10.0.0.34/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?reportName&rs:Format=Excel